# how to get a result of a string inside a string xslt

Tags: string, xslt

I would like to get the result only if N/FRE is present in

```
<codes codetype="subject">N/DJFR,N/LL,N/DJBP,N/DJFB,N/DJWI,N/FRE,N/GENI,N/IEN,N/NENG,N/SUM,N/TPCT</codes>
```

```
<xsl:if test="@codetype='subject'">
<xsl:element namespace="http://www.cedrom-sni.com/schema/newsv1.xsd" name="section">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Answer (score 1):

If the content of the `<codes>` element is a comma-separated list of tokens, you can test the presence of the `N/FRE` token with

```
test="@codetype='subject' and contains(concat(',',.,','), ',N/FRE,')"
```

The surrounding with commas ensures that `<codes>N/FREI</codes>` does not pass the test.